# How do I get the Path from the Windows 8 Photos App as a Share Target?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps

When I try getting the Path from the IStorageItems passed back to me from a Share Target's GetStorageItemsAsync() call when sharing from the Windows 8 Photos app, the Path property for all items returned is empty. The Name (filename) is properly populated. However, I need the actual Path, and there doesn't appear to be a way to get it.

Is this a bug in Windows 8's Photos app, or am I doing something wrong?

My code to get the list of items:

```
this.sharedStorageItems = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetStorageItemsAsync();
```

My code to iterate through the list:

```
// Display the name of the files being shared.
var files = new List<String>();
for (int index = 0; index < this.sharedStorageItems.Count; index++)
    files.Add(String.Concat(this.sharedStorageItems[index].Path, "\\", this.sharedStorageItems[index].Name));
```

The Path above is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the IStorageItem is simply the base class. What's REALLY being returned is an IStorageFile, which includes the base stream of a temporary file created as part of the share process.

So, cast the IStorageItem as an IStorageFile and you'll be in good shape to work with the files returned.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need the path? There's no guarantee you can access the files themselves. For example, if you don't have photo library access, you can't access physical images there. If you don't have internet access, you won't be able to access the ones which come from Facebook and Flickr. Some may also come from SkyDrive, and you may simply have no direct access to those.

Some apps may generate images on the fly, simply creating a StorageItem with the results.

The StorageItem is meant to abstract you from this. You get the actual files being shared rather than some other indirection.

Comment: And if the photo came from the web cam, there is no file name at all.

Comment: Yes, I need the path. I need to upload the files shared. If I don't have the Path, I can't access the file to do so. :)

Comment: I left out a few details:
-- I *do* need the path for file uploading purposes.
-- I have subscribed to *file* events, and will not be responding to Bitmap requests or otherwise.

Comment: I think you're missing a few fundamental points. When you set yourself as a share target for storage items, it doesn't necessarily mean physical files from the drive. The files can come from *anywhere* and often from locations you would not be able to programatically access from your app. If you want to upload, you need to use the StorageItem methods to get the file bits. Here's the HTML/JS version. C#/XAML version is similar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758300.aspx

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but thanks, and I found the C# version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh973051.aspx

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, at least not yet... still researching. The problem is I am working with StandardDataFormats.StorageItems, not StandardDataFormats.Bitmap. I do not receive a Bitmap - only the list of storage items, and the Path is blank. I am not seeing any StorageItem method for getting the file path, and I can't get the bits, either, since all I'm passed is a Name (filename), Path, CreationDate and an option to get Attributes. There is no GetStreamAsync() option or anything similar, so I can't even save an intermediate PNG for upload.

Comment: From the `StorageItem`, verify that it is a `StorageFile` and if so, you can call `OpenReadAsync` to get the bits.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check your share settings through your windows account.  Could be a much easier solution to your issue.